# Is there a concise way to specify two separate nth-children?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Long story short, I was wondering if there was any way to abbreviate this:

```
td:nth-child(1), td:nth-child(2) { }
```

into something like:

```
td:nth-child(1,2) { }
```

or maybe a range like:

```
td:nth-child(1-2) { }
```

Comment: I don't think css has a built in rule for this, but such a thing would be pretty easy to set up with sass

Comment: The basic answer to the question of two separate, arbitrary nth children is no, there isn't a way. But if those children, and only those children, fall within a range that can be specified in terms of an+b, then it's likely possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select the first two columns with just this:

```
td:nth-child(-n+2)
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/bQ2kc/

Article on this: http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

---

The best I can find for any arbitrary range of columns which at least avoids repeating what comes before the nth-child() specifier is this:

```
.test .columns td:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n+2)
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/hfuTa/

Article that showed me how: https://gist.github.com/rondevera/167627

---